# Enumerable/Stream with look ahead

Tags: elixir

I'm beginning to learn Elixir and have come across a challenge that I haven't been able to solve easily.

I'm trying to create function that takes an Enumerable.t and returns another Enumerable.t that includes the next *n* items. It would have slightly different behaviour from Enum.chunk(e, n, 1, []) in that the number iteration count would always equal the original enumerable count. I also need to support Streams

```
@spec lookahead(Enumerable.t, non_neg_integer) :: Enumerable.t
```

This is best illustrated with doctest syntax:

```
iex> lookahead(1..6, 1) |> Enum.to_list
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6]]

iex> lookahead(1..4, 2) |> Enum.to_list
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4]]

iex> Stream.cycle(1..4) |> lookahead(2) |> Enum.take(5)
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,1],[4,1,2],[1,2,3]]

iex> {:ok,io} = StringIO.open("abcd")
iex> IO.stream(io,1) |> lookahead(2) |> Enum.to_list
[["a","b","c"],["b","c","d"],["c","d"],["d"]]
```

I have investigated implementing the Enumerable.t protocol, but haven't quite understood the Enumerable.reduce interface.

Is there any succinct/elegant way of doing this?

My use case is for a small fixed n value (1 or 2) on a binary stream, so extra points for an optimized version. However, for the purpose of learning Elixir I'm interested in a solution across a number of use cases. Performance is important. I will run some benchmarks across various values of n for the solution and publish.

**Benchmark Update - 8th April 2015**

6 workable solutions have been posted. Details of the benchmarks are available at https://gist.github.com/spitsw/fce5304ec6941578e454. Benchmarks were run over a list with 500 items for various values of n.

For n=1 the following result:

```
PatrickSuspend.lookahead    104.90 µs/op
Warren.lookahead            174.00 µs/op
PatrickChunk.lookahead      310.60 µs/op
PatrickTransform.lookahead  357.00 µs/op
Jose.lookahead              647.60 µs/op
PatrickUnfold.lookahead     1484000.00 µs/op
```

For n=50 the following result:

```
PatrickSuspend.lookahead    220.80 µs/op
Warren.lookahead            320.60 µs/op
PatrickTransform.lookahead  518.60 µs/op
Jose.lookahead              1390.00 µs/op
PatrickChunk.lookahead      3058.00 µs/op
PatrickUnfold.lookahead     1345000.00 µs/op (faster than n=1)
```

Comment: I think your last example should return three-element lists, right?

Comment: Yes, @PatrickOscity, the last example should return 3 elements. I have now corrected the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, my first attempt had some performance problems and didn't work with streams that have side-effects, such as IO streams. I took the time to dig deeper into the stream library and finally came up with this solution:

```
defmodule MyStream
  def lookahead(enum, n) do
    step = fn val, _acc -> {:suspend, val} end
    next = &Enumerable.reduce(enum, &1, step)
    &do_lookahead(n, :buffer, [], next, &1, &2)
  end

  # stream suspended
  defp do_lookahead(n, state, buf, next, {:suspend, acc}, fun) do
    {:suspended, acc, &do_lookahead(n, state, buf, next, &1, fun)}
  end

  # stream halted
  defp do_lookahead(_n, _state, _buf, _next, {:halt, acc}, _fun) do
    {:halted, acc}
  end

  # initial buffering
  defp do_lookahead(n, :buffer, buf, next, {:cont, acc}, fun) do
    case next.({:cont, []}) do
      {:suspended, val, next} ->
        new_state = if length(buf) < n, do: :buffer, else: :emit
        do_lookahead(n, new_state, buf ++ [val], next, {:cont, acc}, fun)
      {_, _} ->
        do_lookahead(n, :emit, buf, next, {:cont, acc}, fun)
    end
  end

  # emitting
  defp do_lookahead(n, :emit, [_|rest] = buf, next, {:cont, acc}, fun) do
    case next.({:cont, []}) do
      {:suspended, val, next} ->
        do_lookahead(n, :emit, rest ++ [val], next, fun.(buf, acc), fun)
      {_, _} ->
        do_lookahead(n, :emit, rest, next, fun.(buf, acc), fun)
    end
  end

  # buffer empty, halting
  defp do_lookahead(_n, :emit, [], _next, {:cont, acc}, _fun) do
    {:halted, acc}
  end
end
```

This may look daunting at first, but actually it's not that hard. I will try to break it down for you, but that's hard with a full-fledged example like this.

Let's start with a simpler example instead: A stream that endlessly repeats the value given to it. In order to emit a stream, we can return a function that takes an accumulator and a function as argument. To emit a value, we call the function with two arguments: the value to emit and the accumulator. `acc` The accumulator is a tuple that consists of a command (`:cont`, `:suspend` or `:halt`) and tells us what the consumer wants us to do; the result we need to return depends on the operation. If the stream should be suspended, we return a three-element tuple of the atom `:suspended`, the accumulator and a function that will be called when the enumeration continues (sometimes called "continuation"). For the `:halt` command, we simply return `{:halted, acc}` and for the `:cont` we emit a value by performing the recursive step as described above. The whole thing then looks like this:

```
defmodule MyStream do
  def repeat(val) do
    &do_repeat(val, &1, &2)
  end

  defp do_repeat(val, {:suspend, acc}, fun) do
    {:suspended, acc, &do_repeat(val, &1, fun)}
  end

  defp do_repeat(_val, {:halt, acc}, _fun) do
    {:halted, acc}
  end

  defp do_repeat(val, {:cont, acc}, fun) do
    do_repeat(val, fun.(val, acc), fun)
  end
end
```

Now this is only one part of the puzzle. We can emit a stream, but we don't process an incoming stream yet. Again, to explain how that works it makes sense to construct a simpler example. Here, I will build a function that takes an enumerable and just suspends and re-emits for every value.

```
defmodule MyStream do
  def passthrough(enum) do
    step = fn val, _acc -> {:suspend, val} end
    next = &Enumerable.reduce(enum, &1, step)
    &do_passthrough(next, &1, &2)
  end

  defp do_passthrough(next, {:suspend, acc}, fun) do
    {:suspended, acc, &do_passthrough(next, &1, fun)}
  end

  defp do_passthrough(_next, {:halt, acc}, _fun) do
    {:halted, acc}
  end

  defp do_passthrough(next, {:cont, acc}, fun) do
    case next.({:cont, []}) do
      {:suspended, val, next} ->
        do_passthrough(next, fun.(val, acc), fun)
      {_, _} ->
        {:halted, acc}
    end
  end
end
```

The first clause sets up the `next` function that gets passed down to the `do_passthrough` function. It serves the purpose of getting the next value from the incoming stream. The step function that is internally used defines that we suspend for every item in the stream. The rest is pretty similar except for the last clause. Here, we call the next function with `{:cont, []}` to get a new value and process the result by means of a case statement. If there is a value, we get back `{:suspended, val, next}`, if not, the stream is halted and we pass that through to the consumer.

I hope that clarifies a few things about how to build streams in Elixir manually. Unfortunately, there's an awful lot of boilerplate required to work with streams. If you go back to the `lookahead` implementation now, you will see that there are only tiny differences, which are the actually interesting parts. There are two additional parameters: `state`, which serves to differentiate between the `:buffer` and `:emit` steps, and `buffer` which is pre-filled with `n+1` items in the initial buffering step. In the emit phase, the current buffer is emitted and then shifted to the left on each iteration. We're done when the input stream halts or our stream is halted directly.

---

I am leaving my original answer here for reference:

Here's a solution that uses `Stream.unfold/2` to emit a true stream of values 
according to your specification. This means you need to add `Enum.to_list` to
the end of your first two examples to obtain the actual values.

```
defmodule MyStream do
  def lookahead(stream, n) do
    Stream.unfold split(stream, n+1), fn
      {[], stream} ->
        nil
      {[_ | buf] = current, stream} ->
        {value, stream} = split(stream, 1)
        {current, {buf ++ value, stream}}
    end
  end

  defp split(stream, n) do
    {Enum.take(stream, n), Stream.drop(stream, n)}
  end
end
```

The general idea is that we keep a buf of the previous iterations around. On each iteration, we emit the current buf, take one value from the stream and append it to the end of the buf. This repeats until the buf is empty.

Example:

```
iex> MyStream.lookahead(1..6, 1) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6]]

iex> MyStream.lookahead(1..4, 2) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]

iex> Stream.cycle(1..3) |> MyStream.lookahead(2) |> Enum.take(5)
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: This is a neat solution too! I think the multiple calls to Stream.drop/1 is going to hit performance too as every time it is adding more and more steps to the "drop" stream. Maybe one solution based on yours is to use the fact we can suspend streams. So you get the items you need and suspend it.

Comment: I tried the above solution against an IO.stream. Unfortunately IO.streams have a side effect of not returning the same items on subsequent calls. So I think the split function will cause items to be dropped. I'll add an example in the question.

Comment: @JoséValim thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into this and try to improve my answer. It feels kind of wrong to pass around the stream in the accumulator. I guess that would mean that I have to build this completely manually, or is there a helper function for lower level stream building that I am missing out?

Comment: @Warren I can't check right now, but it should work since the previously emitted values are stored in a buffer, which is just a list.

Comment: @PatrickOscity take a look at the functions in the Stream module. Using Stream.unfold/1 is fine but you can also simply return a function that expects two arguments, the accumulator and a function, and use that to build a stream too.

Comment: @Warren is right. It is going to skip items for streams with side-effects!

Comment: @JoséValim thanks for your comments. I will look into it, but I don't seem to be able to grasp how to use suspension with `Stream.unfold`. Regarding the side-effect problem: do we need to take a completely different approach for streams with side-effects then?

Comment: It is possible to have one approach that works fine with every stream. The issue in your case is that you always drop the first x items, then the next x items, but the stream is not replayable, so dropping x and taking x items will actually perform 2x operations in the stream.

Comment: @Warren just wanted to give you an update: I am working on an improved solution, but I need to look into the inner workings of streams first and I am a bit busy right now. I hope I'll eventually come up with something that works – this problem really bugs me ;-)

Comment: @PatrickOscity, this problem really bugs me too. I thought it would be simple. I've posted my own solution which uses suspend but I'm interested interested to see other answers.

Comment: @Warren ok I see you answered the question yourself, but here's my approach, maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: @PatrickOscity great answer! Thoroughly explained and works perfectly. I certainly learnt a few things from your answer.

Comment: @Warren I found that this whole thing feels to complicated and have proposed yet another solution to the problem: `Stream.mutate/3` abstracts the process of building a stream that doesn't have a one-to-one mapping of input to output values. Here's the core mailing list post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/wiMbAedj9X8

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inefficient implementation of such function:

```
defmodule Lookahead do
  def lookahead(enumerable, n) when n > 0 do
    enumerable
    |> Stream.chunk(n + 1, 1, [])
    |> Stream.flat_map(fn list ->
        length = length(list)
        if length < n + 1 do
          [list|Enum.scan(1..n-1, list, fn _, acc -> Enum.drop(acc, 1) end)]
        else
          [list]
        end
      end)
  end
end
```

It builds on top of @hahuang65 implementation, except that we use a `Stream.flat_map/2` to check the length of each emitted item, adding the missing ones as soon as we detect the emitted item got shorter.

A hand-written implementation from scratch would be faster because we would not need to call `length(list)` on every iteration. The implementation above may be fine though if `n` is small. If n is fixed, you could even pattern match on the generated list explicitly.

Comment: This seems to work well. The function does return some extra empty lists ( [] ) at the end in some circumstances though. eg lookahead([1,2],1) returns [[1, 2], [2], [], []]. I'm enjoying studying every response!

Answer (score 3):

[I had started a discussion about my proposed `Stream.mutate` method on the elixir core mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/wiMbAedj9X8), where Peter Hamilton suggested another way of solving this problem. By using [`make_ref` to create a globally unique reference](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#make_ref/0), we can create a padding stream and concatenate it with the original enumerable to continue emitting after the original stream has halted. This can then either be used in conjunction with `Stream.chunk`, which means we need to remove the unwanted references in a last step:

```
def lookahead(enum, n) do
  stop = make_ref
  enum
  |> Stream.concat(List.duplicate(stop, n))
  |> Stream.chunk(n+1, 1)
  |> Stream.map(&Enum.reject(&1, fn x -> x == stop end))
end
```

I think this is the prettiest solution yet, from a syntactical point of view. Alternatively, we can use `Stream.transform` to build the buffer manually, which is quite similar to the manual solution I proposed earlier:

```
def lookahead(enum, n) do
  stop = make_ref
  enum
  |> Stream.concat(List.duplicate(stop, n+1))
  |> Stream.transform([], fn val, acc ->
    case {val, acc} do
      {^stop, []}                         -> {[]   , []           }
      {^stop, [_|rest] = buf}             -> {[buf], rest         }
      {val  , buf} when length(buf) < n+1 -> {[]   , buf ++ [val] }
      {val  , [_|rest] = buf}             -> {[buf], rest ++ [val]}
    end
  end)
end
```

I haven't benchmarked these solutions but I suppose the second one, although slightly clunkier, should perform a little bit better because it does not have to iterate over each chunk.

By the way, the second solution can be written without the case statement [once Elixir allows to use the pin operator in function heads (probably in v1.1.0)](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2061):

```
def lookahead(enum, n) do
  stop = make_ref
  enum
  |> Stream.concat(List.duplicate(stop, n+1))
  |> Stream.transform([], fn
    ^stop, []                         -> {[]   , []           }
    ^stop, [_|rest] = buf             -> {[buf], rest         }
    val  , buf when length(buf) < n+1 -> {[]   , buf ++ [val] }
    val  , [_|rest] = buf             -> {[buf], rest ++ [val]}
  end)
end
```

Comment: @Warren it is really interesting to see how this can be solved in so many different ways. Thanks for sharing your benchmarks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Stream.chunk/4

Would look something like this:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  def lookahead(enum, amount) do
    Stream.chunk(enum, amount + 1, 1, [])
  end
end
```

With your inputs:

```
iex(2)> MyMod.lookahead(1..6, 1) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6]]

iex(3)> MyMod.lookahead(1..4, 2) |> Enum.to_list
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4]]

iex(4)> Stream.cycle(1..3) |> MyMod.lookahead(1) |> Enum.take(5)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Hm this might not be a perfect solution. I think something is up where it's consuming the rest of the Enumerable when using Stream.chunk...

Comment: The padding happens just once in chunk and not multiple times. So you indeed won't see the last `[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution uses Stream.resource and the suspend capability of Enumerable.reduce. All of the examples pass.

In short, it uses Enumerable.reduce to build a list. It then suspends the reducer on each iteration removing the head of the list and added the newest item on the tail of the list. Finally, it produces the trailer of the stream when the reducer is :done or :halted. All this is coordinated using Stream.resource.

This would be more efficient if a FIFO queue was used instead of a list for each iteration.

Please provide feedback for any simplifications, efficiencies or bugs

```
def Module
  def lookahead(enum, n) when n >= 0 do
    reducer = fn -> Enumerable.reduce(enum, {:cont, {0, []}}, fn
      item, {c, list} when c < n  -> {:cont, {c+1, list ++ [item]}} # Build up the first list
      item, {c, list} when c == n -> {:suspend, {c+1, list ++ [item]}} # Suspend on first full list
      item, {c, [_|list]} -> {:suspend, {c, list ++ [item]}} # Remove the first item and emit
      end)
    end

    Stream.resource(reducer,
      fn
        {:suspended, {_, list} = acc , fun} -> {[list], fun.({:cont, acc})}
        {:halted, _} = result -> lookahead_trail(n, result) # Emit the trailing items
        {:done, _} = result -> lookahead_trail(n, result) # Emit the trailing items
      end,
      fn
        {:suspended, acc, fun} -> fun.({:halt, acc}) # Ensure the reducer is halted after suspend
        _ ->
      end)
  end

  defp lookahead_trail(n, acc) do
    case acc do
      {action, {c, [_|rest]}} when c > n -> {[], {action, {c-1, rest}}} # List already emitted here
      {action, {c, [_|rest] = list}} -> {[list], {action, {c-1, rest}}} # Emit the next tail item
      acc -> {:halt, acc } # Finish of the stream
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I really like how relatively terse your approach turned out. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

I might be late with answer, but it can be done with [Stream.chunk_while/4](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_while/4),

```
defmodule Denis do
  def lookahead(enumerable) do
    chunk_fun = fn
      element, nil -> {:cont, element}
      element, acc -> {:cont, [acc, element], element}
    end

    after_fun = fn
      nil -> {:cont, []}
      [] -> {:cont, []}
      acc -> {:cont, [acc], []}
    end

    enumerable
    |> Stream.chunk_while(nil, chunk_fun, after_fun)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After drawing inspiration from Warren, I made this. Basic usage:

```
ex> {peek, enum} = StreamSplit.peek 1..10, 3
{[1, 2, 3], #Function<57.77324385/2 in Stream.transform/3>}
iex> Enum.take(enum, 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

https://hex.pm/packages/stream_split